# Preventing access to static file served on blob in Angular 6 app that itself is hosted on the blob?

Tags: angular, azure, blob, angular6, cdn

I have an app that is served as static content and is angular 6 app.
I have an assets folder which contains a pdf file, that I only want to be accessed  by logged in users via the internal link in the application itself.

So now, the issue is that if I have a link to that doc, I am able to access that file without being logged. (since this is static content served on blob as well as SPA angular 6 app).

What is the best way to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Since public read access can only be set at container-level, you'll have to make another private blob container and put the assets there.

Then you'll need a back-end service that generates a SAS token for the user so they can get temporary access to the file.
Or you can use an Azure AD access token to access the blob, though that feature is still in preview (and requires you use AAD for auth).